# Made a code for insertion sort, declared a sorted and an unsorted array, but the unsorted array is output as a sorted array at the end

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, insertion-sort

```
def InsSort(myList):
    UBound = len(myList)

    for i in range(1,UBound):
        NextItem = myList[i]
        position = i - 1

        while position>=0 and myList[position]>NextItem:
            myList[position+1] = myList[position]
            position = position - 1
        myList[position+1] = NextItem


UnsortList = []
n = int(input("Enter number of elements in the List:\n"))
for j in range(0,n):
    element = int(input("Input element:\n"))
    UnsortList.append(element)
print(UnsortList)

myList = UnsortList

InsSort(myList)

print(str(UnsortList)+" is now sorted --> "+str(myList))
```

I let the user create their own array "UnsortList" using their input, I then copy it to "myList", and call the funtion InSort(myList) to sort the "myList" array, but when it excecutes `print(str(UnsortList)+" is now sorted --> "+str(myList))`, `str(UnsortList)` shows up as the sorted "myList" as well

An example output:

First it outputs the unsorted array via `print(UnsortList)`

> [-9, 3, 6, 1, -3, 55, 22, -18]

Then where it is supposed to print the Unsorted and sorted array via `print(str(UnsortList)+" is now sorted --> "+str(myList))`, this is what it outputs:

> [-18, -9, -3, 1, 3, 6, 22, 55] is now sorted --> [-18, -9, -3, 1, 3, 6, 22, 55]

The output I want is:

> [-9, 3, 6, 1, -3, 55, 22, -18] is now sorted --> [-18, -9, -3, 1, 3, 6, 22, 55]

What could be the solution to this?

Thanks to **OldBill**, I realised `myList = UnsortList`  does not create a copy of the list as I intended, the correct syntax is supposed to be `myList = UnsortList.copy()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assignment *myList = UnsortList* is meaningless as *myList* will just be a reference to *UnSortList*

Your implementation of the insertion sort is flawed.

Using hard-coded values:

```
def insertionSort(array):
    for step in range(1, len(array)):
        key = array[step]
        j = step - 1       
        while j >= 0 and key < array[j]:
            array[j + 1] = array[j]
            j -= 1
        array[j + 1] = key

myList = [1, 6, -18, 22, -3, -9, 55, 3]
insertionSort(myList)
print(myList)
```

**Output:**

```
[-18, -9, -3, 1, 3, 6, 22, 55]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,

What I was thinking by using ```myList = UnsortList``` is that myList is now a copy of UnsortList, so I will let the function sort myList only and keep UnsortList as it was input by the user.

This is in order to show the difference between the Unsorted and Sorted list to the user at the end output as I tried to do so using ```print(str(UnsortList)+" is now sorted --> "+str(myList))```

Comment: @EmergencyEgg It is not a copy. If you want a copy then use the list's built-in copy() method. Or you can slice like this: myList = UnsortList[:]

Comment: Oh I see, I just realised that it's not the same as copying, thank you so much, it outputs correctly now !